# Making Eclipse Maven repository inside the project

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc, maven-2

I'm a real beginner to Maven and Spring framework in eclipse so excuse me if this sounds trivial..

I have created a MVC web project in eclipse using the STS plugin on my windows computer, but my problem is that the location of the jar and configuration files that maven is set to by default is: C:\Users\MyName.m2\repository

This is a problem for me because eventually I'm going to make a WAR file out of my project and deploy it on a Linux machine, which does not have Maven installed on it.

My question is, is it possible to take all the jar files in my Maven repository, and make a local repository on the project itself rather than on an absolute path on the machine (sort of like a lib folder within the WEB-INF in the project that will hold all the maven jars and that maven will direct itself to it), and thus making the transition to the Linux machine smooth

I understand there is this classpath variable named M2_REPO, but doesn't seem to be editable or accept relative path rather than absolute.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using maven and you are adding your dependencies on your pom.xml, then all the dependencies with a scope of "compile" will be added to your final war file created by the maven war plugin under the WEB-INF/lib folder, this means that you should not worried about having maven in your linux server, since the war file that you are going to deploy will contain all the necessary dependencies. If you want to confirm this, just create a package of your project using "mvn clean package" and check the "target" folder generated by maven, you will see a "war" file, and you can unzip your file to check what contains.